# Почему не работают события hover?

Tags: css

Не могу понять почему не работает вот такого вида событие hover

```
.way1:hover .arrow{
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srb72wnu/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что `.arrow` не внутри `.way1`, `.way2`, `.way3`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.way1,
.way2,
.way3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-position: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%
}

.way1 {
  background: red;
  top: -5px;
}

.way2 {
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.way3 {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.center {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite, pulse2 2s infinite;
}

.arrow {
  transition: 2s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.way1:hover~.arrow {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.way2:hover~.arrow {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.way3:hover~.arrow {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="way1"></div>
<div class="way2"></div>
<div class="way3"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

---

> почему не работают данные if условия в sass - https://jsfiddle.net/2ysenbxL/3/

```
/* Почему не работает? */
$arrowPosition: way1
.way1:hover~.arrow
  @if $arrowPosition == way2
    transform: rotateZ(290deg)
    $arrowPosition: way1
  @else
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
    $arrowPosition: way1
.way2:hover~.arrow
  @if $arrowPosition == way1
    transform: rotateZ(-134deg)
    $arrowPosition: way2
  @else
    transform: rotateZ(225deg)
    $arrowPosition: way2
  transform: rotateZ(225deg) /* <- лишняя строчка */
.way3:hover~.arrow
  @if $arrowPosition == way1
    transform: rotateZ(135deg)
    $arrowPosition: way3
  @else
    transform: rotateZ(225deg)
    $arrowPosition: way3
```

У Вас там лишняя строчка `transform: rotateZ(225deg)`.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, если не трудно можете подсказать почему не работают данные if условия в sass https://jsfiddle.net/2ysenbxL/3/

Comment: @Бармалей Что значит "не работают"? У Вас там лишняя строчка `transform: rotateZ(225deg)`.

Answer (score -1):

У вас стиль применяется к классу arrow, элемент которого находится внутри элемента с классом way1.

Если вам нужно применить `hover` на `.way1`

```
.way1:hover{
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}
```

Если вам нужно применить `hover` на `.arrow` который внутри `.way1`

```
.way1 .arrow:hover{
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}
```